# which character set to use in paypal adm panel when having a databse encoded in latin_swedish

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, paypal

I have a db encoded in latin_swedish and i cannot change it's encoding.

Now i'm using my PayPal app to take shipping parameters and to put them in the DB but i can't insert strings that contain special characters (the à as an example) so i have to find the best solution to change the best encoding type in PP for the latin_swedish mySql encoding, because i have to be able to make the insert with special characters too.

Do you know this problem and do you know which encoding is the best? I've found that in PP adm there's no latin_swedish encoding option.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use html entities...

[`htmlentities()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

[Convertion table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: I've tried this command, but i have no positive response. Always the problem remains the same

Comment: how did you try to use it? give me the code... are you setting proper flags and encoding?

Comment: I did it. I used the ini_set(charset...) at the beginning of every page, i altered the database to utf_8 and the administration panel too, i've added the charset... in the meta tag

Comment: But you need to add to `htmlentities();` function `UTF-8` as third argument... default is mostly `ISO`...

Comment: i saw just now! last time was very late, i'll try this and let you know

Comment: Flash nothing happened, i don't know what to do anymore...is there a difference between using the htmlentities() before writing the string and specifying it for the parameters into the string?

Comment: Ah you probably have bad flags... Use `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE`